# Android Drawer Layout is Displaying under fragment content

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I am adding a drawer layout to my Activity which uses fragments.  I've implemented this just as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) per the android documentation.  And the drawer layout Adapter and View all work in that they show up, but the drawer extends "under" the fragment content.  Here is a picture of what is happening:  [image]

Does anyone know why this might be?  My code for the activity's xml, and the activity add fragment is below:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_list); // for drawer navigation
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,
            new AlarmListFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    setUpDrawer(fragmentManager);
}

    private void setUpDrawer(FragmentManager fm) {
    String[] drawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.drawer_array);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ListView drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.item_nav_drawer, drawerItems));
    // Set the list's click listener
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new
            DrawerItemClickListener(drawer,drawerList,drawerItems,fm));
}
```

#### Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/alarm_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Do I have to set a z-index somewhere?  I can provide any further info needed I'd just really like to figure this out!

Comment: You're adding the fragment directly to the main activity container which has the id `android.R.id.content` which hold the `DrawerLayout`. You should be adding the fragment to a content `FrameLayout` **inside** the drawer widget.

Answer (score 1):

I don't what produces this issue , but to solve it u have to add the fragment to the content of your FrameLayout which has the id = `content_frame`.

So edit this line

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,
        new AlarmListFragment());
```

to be

```
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,
        new AlarmListFragment());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the drawer layout below your Fragment container in your XML. this will render the DrawerLayout in the forward view of the app. just be sure not to cover the fragment container with the parent container of the drawer so that your fragment will be accessible when you need it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_parent_container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout
             android:id=@+id/drawer_pane"
             android:layout_width="250dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="end" />
        <ListView xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:id="@+id/menu_list"
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i want the fragment container below the toolbar that is inside the drawerlayout and above the bottom navigation view , how can i do that